# How to fix a corrupted MicroSD card?

Tags: sd-card

Somehow my MicroSD card became **read-only**.  There is no physical write lock switch on the card.

I can't store new files in it, and I also am unable to delete any of the existing files. Whenever I try to delete a file, it reappears again.

I had tried to format it from both ubuntu 22.04 lts and windows 10 but it didn't helped. The files still reappears.

What's going on, and is there a way for me to fix the SD card so that I can change the data on it again?

Comment: Have you checked on another system to make sure the SD card is in fact corrupt, rather than just needing a file system cleanup/check?  If the issue is replicated on another computer that is not Linux then the issue is the SD card is likely outlived its read/writes cycle and should be replaced - you should copy the data on the card you want to keep to your computer, get a new SD card, and then copy the data back to the SD card.  Keep in mind that SD cards have a **limited** number of read/writes they can do, so if the SD card has been written to a ton of times, it's likely just worn out.

Comment: Have you tried to empty the trash bin on the card?